# Recovery authy 2fa tokens

Tags: recover, authy

Looks like I forgot my backup password on authy for PC however, I can still access all my 2fa accounts on mobile authy for android. I want to know if it is possible to recover or reset my backup password to make it work on the computer again.

I did try to remove a 2fa account and set it up again from mobile authy but on pc, it still asks me to put the backup password to access it.  please guide me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Authy developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid the backup password is used to encrypt your backups and is [never saved anywhere by Authy](https://support.authy.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001950787-Backups-password-Master-password-and-PIN-protection-with-Authy). The password is needed to decrypt the backups and without it, you can't and there is no way to recover the password (if Authy had a copy of your password, we could access your codes).

To completely start again you will need to find where Authy Desktop saved your backups file and remove it. Then the app won't ask for the password to decrypt it. I don't know where that is though, as I'm on a Mac.

Comment: and where are those passwords kept on OSX? I had Authy in Chrome, then switched to iOS version, now when I tried to use Chrome version again (after 1-2 years hiatus), ALL my accounts require backup password, which I had never set up (or just assumed it's the same as Authy master password). Now without knowing what backup password is, I'm freaking out about losing all my tokens (all tokens in iOS Authy are still open, but i'm afraid same thing would happen to them in case of reinstall or smth).